# heredoc on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to use the `Heredoc Method` described here:
http://www.developfortheweb.com/2009/03/multi-line-strings-in-javascript/

```
var string = (<r><![CDATA[

   The text string goes here.  Since this is a XML CDATA section,
   stuff like <> work fine too, even if definitely invalid XML. 

]]></r>).toString();
```

I can't make it work on node.js. I tested it on client side - it works on Firefox, but Chrome.

How should I use **this** method on node.js?

Thanks!

Comment: This works on Firefox because it supports [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) syntax. But E4X [was deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X), so this is the sole browser to support "heredoc" syntax.

Comment: Nowadays the solution is obviously Template Literals (it didn't exist when I asked this questions). So to have a multi-line string in JS - just surround it by back-ticks.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this blog posts tells you something else, **JavaScript does not have heredoc strings.**

So you should not use it at all - it is a dirty hack. The reason why it works in some browsers is that they allow inline XML. NodeJS probably doesn't because well, it's ugly and dirty.

Comment: For use with Node, there are other dirty hacks of course, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5571069/893780 :)

Answer (score 2):

Now with ES6 it's easy to do that using [Template Strings](http://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

The reason I was looking for it was a need to pass multi-line html text (keeping nice html indents and without splitting it to js strings) as an argument to a template engine.

Finally for my problem I just created a template engine with a heredoc block - so if you anybody is looking for heredoc just for more convenient way to write his templates - the https://github.com/AlexLibs/hot can be used (the module is registered on npm).